# How to index entire GOPATH for existing project in Goland?

Tags: go, goland

When I create a project, I forgot to check [index entire GOPATH]. So currently, the project can't find third party modules.

Even though I checked `[index entire GOPATH]` option for this project in `Preferences | Go | GOPATH | Project GOPATH`, the project doesn't index the entire GOPATH.

---

Edit:

I deleted .idea directory and opened the project again, it works fine now.

Comment: I need more details on this. Is the GOPATH value configured in the correct place? Can you update the question with a screenshot of that settings screen? Can you also give me a screenshot of the project panel with the whole External Libraries section expanded where the GOPATH entry is?

Comment: @dlsniper I uploaded a video [here](https://youtu.be/KI085FfgufM) on youtube.

Comment: P.S. you don't need to delete `.idea` directory. Just refresh the IDE (by closing it and reopening) and it will work.

Comment: @Lansana I also rebooted computer :)